# cdi unable to inject Object into ContainerRequestFilter in jax rs

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi

I am trying to inject my service layer object into class which extend ContainerFilterRequest but i m getting null pointer exception, My Obejct is not  getting dependency after the injection point

Here is my code in jax rs

```
@PreMatching
@Provider
public class RequestInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {


@Inject
private CompanyUserService companyUserService;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    ......
    ......
   //not initialized yet
   Optional<CompanyUser> user = this.companyUserService.getByUserName(apiSecurityDetail.getSubject());
}
```

and here is my service object

```
@Named
class CompanyUserServiceImpl implements CompanyUserService {


@Inject
private CompanyUserDao companyUserDao;

@Inject
private CompanyUserConverter companyUserConverter;

@Inject
private CompanyUserValidator companyUserValidator;

//other code
}
```

I have explicitly added @RequestScoped in my other module which is working fine, but when i added `@RequestScoped` here in this filter class, it wont filter method and without `@RequestScoped` and with @Dependent Scope their is no initialization of object.

According to JBOSS DOC:

1. If a JAX-RS root resource does not define a scope explicitly, it is bound to the Request scope.
2. If a JAX-RS Provider or javax.ws.rs.Application subclass does not define a scope explicitly, it is bound to the Application scope.

In my case I have defined all my root jax-rs class with `@RequestScoped`. It will be big help if you guy put some sense into this confusion. Thank you

while adding @requestScope in class level

following stacktrace show

```
    08:15:57,975 INFO  [np.com.drose.parkgarau.platform.DBConnectionFactory] (default task-35)  inside DataSource generation
08:15:57,976 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-35) RESTEASY002025: Unknown exception while executing GET /vehicles/calculation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request Context is missing
    at np.com.drose.parkgarau.platform.ParkGarumContextHolder.getContext(ParkGarumContextHolder.java:14)
    at np.com.drose.parkgarau.platform.DataSourceConnectionPool.getDataSource(DataSourceConnectionPool.java:65)
    at np.com.drose.parkgarau.platform.DataSourceConnectionPool$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getDataSource(Unknown Source)
    at np.com.drose.parkgarau.platform.DBConnectionFactory.createConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethodProducer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:181)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:842)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ParameterInjectionPointImpl.getValueToInject(ParameterInjectionPointImpl.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.getParameterValues(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:150)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:116)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:842)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:389)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:742)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:842)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:389)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.JaxrsInjectionTarget.inject(JaxrsInjectionTarget.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at np.com.drose.parkgarau.interceptors.RequestInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.filter(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:133)
```

Comment: What app server are you deploying to?  Wildfly? What version?  Do you have a sub-class of `Application` with singletons? What does the code look like with `@RequestScoped`?

Comment: Im on Apache web profile 7 and i hava Application with Singleton @JohnAment

Comment: Can you post what that looks like?

Comment: @JohnAment sir can you look over it?

Comment: you still didn't post your application class.  the stack helps, but to point out you're not using "apache web profile" I'm guessing you're on wildfly? what version?